# Can this Motor shield support other arduino functions?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, arduino-motor-shield

http://www.flipkart.com/grab-em-l293d-motor-driver-arduino-shield/p/itmehvzzpzj4wyby?pid=ETYEHVZZFFHRFMFG

I want to ask whether this shield will allow me to use the free pins of arduino for other functions?

Comment: Anything that's not connected to something on the shield can be wired to something else of your choice. The trick, though, is to know what is connected to where on the board. Is there a schematic?

Comment: @Majenko Schematic is what I was searching for but I could not find any, all i could dig up is this page,

Comment: Then all you can do is buy one and inspect it closely and follow tracks around. It looks to use a shift register it its core, so will be using very few pins.

Comment: @Majenko Alright thanks, the only problem is I have already spent 90 percent of my pocket money, so I wanted to double check anyways thanks, I shall order it

Comment: As Majenko said, most pins probably aren't used. The only problem is to access the unused pins. As the shield goes into the female headers on the UNO, those are no longer accessible. Looking at the board, they only added some throughholes for pins A0-A5.

Comment: @Gerben I got the shield delivered and actually it came with female header seaters on the top which can make it stackable. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this motor shield can allow other components to be used. You just have to make sure that the pins being used by the shield are not used by you for other tasks. Generally all shields are designed such that they do not hamper the productivity of arduino. What use would only a motor driver be? Therefore they ensure that they do not block other pins.